# Why don't browsers respect LC_TIME?

Tags: firefox, chrome, locale

I'm using en_US for system language, but pl_PL for date format. It works OK in the entire system, and running `date` gives me a correctly formatted date. It also shows Polish as Time format in the GUI Language Settings.

But in any browser (Chrome, Chromium, Firefox) I have US format! For example in Date input, Date in JS etc...

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString())
// shows      9/26/2021, 3:29:46 PM
// should be  26.09.2021, 15:29:46
```

locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

To reproduce this use: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tolocalestring, or create a file called `index.html` with the following contents:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
  </head>
  <body>
    Hi!
    <script>
     console.log(new Date().toLocaleString())
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

And then open this file using any value of `LC_ALL` and browser combination you care to try:

```
LC_ALL=el_GR.utf8 firefox index.html
```

Then, look at the javascript console (usually available by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>) and you will see the date format ignores the LC setting.

I also have en for language and pl for dates on a Windows machine and it works fine. Why can't Linux do this?

I was dealing with this for year now. All I can find in google is people with similar issue but without solution or problems with date format in system.

System: Linux Mint 20 Xfce

Comment: I can change to the desired behavior only if I change the language settings of the browser (tested on firefox) itself. Looks like the browsers use their own internal settings and ignore the system-wide locale.

Comment: could you use smth like `console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('pl-PL'));` ?

Comment: @Andra nice! But presumably, the OP needs this to be displayed using the locale settings of the user visiting their page.

Comment: @terdon but isn't it then a bug which must be reported?

Comment: Could be, @Andra, that would depend on what specification the browsers are supposed to follow. We can't know if it's a bug without knowing the intended behavior.

Comment: @terdon well, but it works in Windows

Comment: Looks like this is implementation-dependent and not a requirement of the javascript specs. See [How/Where does JavaScript detect the default locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46146573)

Comment: @terdon about changing this in browser. I'm using mainly chromium/chrome and there is no settings for that, just language change.

Comment: @chojnicki yes, changing the language also changes the date format. I realize that isn't a good solution though which is why I only mentioned it in a comment. That said, based on the SO post I linked to in my previous comment and on the official specs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), this is a javascript thing and not a *nix issue. It comes down to choices made by the developers of the browsers you use. I doubt we'll be able to help.

Comment: Firefox supports switching from the config locale to the OS locale: https://superuser.com/a/1804828. But is isn't `LC_TIME` specific.